# Using Compiled typescript module in another typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundling-and-minification

Trying to get up to speed with typescript and module bundling system and stuck against some scenarios.

I have created a functions library in typescript, lets say **"code1.ts"** and compiled it and generated a java script **"code1.js"** out of it.

Now I have hosted **"code1.js"** on web server as **"http://server1/lib/code1.js"** so that I can use it in a different web project.

In my new web project I am writing typescript and I want to use some function/methods from the **"http://server1/lib/code1.js"**.

With above setup I am looking answers for the following queries:

1. First how to refer and get module references of **"code1.ts"**  in **"code2.ts"** from the **"http://server1/lib/code1.js"**. I don't want to embed the **"code1.js"** in the web project, I just want to refer it from this URL.
2. Secondly if I use any web bundling system like webpack etc. in the web project I want to avoid downloading and embedding of the **"http://server1/lib/code1.js"** content in the web project distribution build.

Comment: If you're talking about running a remote script, sure it can be done, but its typically a security concern unless you verify it cryptographically. 

1 doesn't seem to be dependent on TypeScript.
And you should ask a seperate question for 2 as webpack is its own beast.

Comment: It might help to read up on Declaration Files.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Though my problem is not yet solved but seeing these documents I feel I am heading in right direction.